# Which of these 2 approaches is the best route to learn to build a question answer chatbot?

Tags: nlp, sequence-to-sequence, gpt, chatbot

### Quick background on what I am trying to accomplish:

I have been working on a project in my company that requires about 300 people across the world to follow quite a large set of rules and guidelines. instead of sharing documents that people can reference for these rules, I am looking to build a chatbot. This chatbot will take all my documents as inputs and then can be used by the end users to answer any of their questions related to processes and guidelines

### What research I have done so far:

Broadly, I believe my 2 main routes are

1. build a chatbot from scratch. I found a good Udemy course on seq2seq architecture that can allow me to build this chatbot
2. Build an application(chatbot) on top of existing algorithms like GPT-3 or BERT

### What help I need:

1. I am confused which of the above 2 is the best approach. I guess I need more information on the pros and cons of both.
2. Is 1) is the right approach, is seq2seq too outdated to learn about it now? Should I find a course that uses another architecture?
3. If 2) is the right approach, I am struggling to find a resource that can teach me how to build this chatbot including a simple GUI

Note: I have experience working with CNN and a little bit with RNN as well. I have extensive experience with Python, none with HTML or Java

Answer (score 1):

I would choose option 2 (Build an application(chatbot) on top of existing algorithms like GPT-3 or BERT) for your particular use case, specifically GPT.

For your case, it seems that you are trying to build a chatbot, and for such purposes, it is better to use a large generative language model such as GPT as there are already many resources. GPT, after training has the ability to generate human-like responses to text input which is from what I can tell your use case.

Additionally this won't require much machine learning knowledge as most of the heavy lifting is done by OpenAI for GPT-3 or you can use Transformers from HuggingFace for GPT-2, GPT-NeoX-20B and etc.

For resources:

- [How To Build a GPT-3 Chatbot with Python](https://jman4190.medium.com/how-to-build-a-gpt-3-chatbot-with-python-7b83e55805e6) -> you can change the GUI as it utilizes an API implementation
- [The AI Chatbot Handbook – How to Build an AI Chatbot with Redis, Python, and GPT](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-build-an-ai-chatbot-with-redis-python-and-gpt/) -> they use GPT-J-6B but you can change that and follow this as a guide.

Comment: thank you for the response. This is helpful. How would I provide my own data on rules and guidelines to GPT? Via the prompt?